# Project Clean errors

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have imported a project that i suspect was built in eclipse on a Linux machine to my Android Studio on a Windows Machine.

Many issues were flagged regarding file types, minsdkversion etc etc which i tried solving but this latest is perhaps caused by my attempts, not sure.

I have >100 errors in my vXX\values.xml file where XX is 11, 14 and 21, examples;

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\AutoSync\autoSync\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\values-v11\values.xml
Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\AutoSync\autoSync\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\values-v14\values.xml
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\AutoSync\autoSync\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\values-v21\values.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
```

when i open the offending files i see errors such as: 'cannot resolve symbol "android:actionModeShareDrawable"' in code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionModeShareDrawable">?actionModeShareDrawable</item>
    </style>
```

I see comments in the file saying:

```
   <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-dev/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml -->
```

Now I suspect from research i either need to download more APIs (i have 19, 20 and 21 only i think) or i need to adjust my build.Gradle somehow but im not sure on the solution. my build.Gradle says the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.cvas.autosync"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':gPITCommonautosync')
    compile project(':restApiAutoSync')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-saripaar-1.0.3 .jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
}
```

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\AutoSync\autoSync\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\values-v11\values.xml

Looks like you are using latest version of `AppCompat` library. From v21 itself it needs API level 21 (Android 5.0) for successful compilation. So your guess is right change `compileSdkVersion` to `21` in your gradle file.

Comment: Fantastic, that's got it running the clean successfully anyway, now the fun starts ;) how did you know AppCompat needed v21, from experience?

Comment: AppCompat  library with version 21 needs that. You seem to be using 22. As for how did I know... I faced same issue some time back :)